# onload trigger .click jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers, onload

below is my onload function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tops > ul > li > a').click(
    function () {
        var showThis = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#panels > div').hide();
        $('#' + showThis).show();
        $('.single_hide').hide();
        $('#' + showThis + '_edit').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

How do I trigger a click function of an element by name?

I tried `$('#myelement').trigger('click');` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myelement').click();
```

should do it

Comment: this is same code as `$('#myelement').trigger('click');` which OP said didn't work

Comment: you are right. I have triggered the click but the element which I triggered is being hidden in the same .ready function. Totally stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For Click Event :

`$("#myElement").click(function() {`

`)};`

For Trigger Event :

`$("YourTriggeredElementId/class").trigger();`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#element').on('click' , function () {
         //Do your stuff
   });
});
```

or you can try like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click' , '#element' , function () {
         //Do your stuff
   });
});
```